# Extracting rows from tabular data based on date range

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a table with 10 columns. One of them is a date column and I want to get data for a specific date range. For example, I have data from the year 2016 and onwards, but I want to fetch data only for the duration 01/01/2018 to 12/31/2018. Is it possible to get this data using `awk` command?

Comment: can u share few lines of the table...

Comment: Depending on the date format, you can use string comparison. Otherwise, gawk or mawk are good choices as they have builtin time conversion functions: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html

Answer (score 2):

You can reformat the date in a more useful (and less ambiguous) YYYY/mm/dd format and use string comparison.

```
awk -v date_column=8 '
   {date = substr($date_column, 7, 4)"/"substr($date_column, 1, 5)}
   date >= "2018/01/01" && date <= "2018/12/31"'
```